# Nada acontece ao dar Run em projeto Java no IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Estou tentando rodar um projeto em Java mas ao ir em "Run" -> "Run" ou Alt+Shift+F10 e não acontece nada. O terminal não mostra nada, mesmo tendo System.out no main. Só que meus colegas estão com o mesmo projeto rodando no Intellij em suas máquinas. O projeto está devidamente sincronizado via GitHub Desktop.

Já tentei de tudo, mas quando dá run ele não executa e só abre uma Janela de de Configurar o Run com templates, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Os prints estão em sequência:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí eu vou na aba Run e clico em Run

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então abre um menu pra configurar a execução. Eu já selecionei aplication alí e tentei indicar qual é a classe main, mas o Intellij não me deixa botar ela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No template "Application" eu digito o nome da classe main, mesmo assim o sistema não me deixa dar Run.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu projeto não está configurado corretamente. O símbolo vermelho no nome das classes diz que não está considerando como código.

Modifique em `File > Project Structure > Modules`

Verifique ser o `src` está correto.

Answer (score 1):

**Tive o mesmo problema. Resolvi assim:**

**Exclua a pasta ".idea" do projeto, feche o projeto e o IntelliJ e abra novamente. O próprio IntelliJ criará novamente a pasta ".idea" com as configurações corretas.**

*Obs: Se houver a necessidade de indicar o JDK instalado na máquina o próprio IntelliJ indicará o que está faltando informar (tudo no mouse mesmo).*

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).